# Get user name from url and set as string. But its not returning anything

Tags: php, url-parameters

I am trying to return the current username. I get the user name from the URL and access by `$_GET['user']` method.

But when i try with the get method it will not return the name, instead its returning empty.

```
echo $_GET['user']; // giving myname

$userName=$_GET["user"];

function getUserName()
{
global $userName;       
    if(isset($userName)){   
        return $userName;
    }else{
        return "defaultuser";
    }
}
```

I tried this, too:
`$userName="".$_GET['user']."";`

But when I give simply `$userName="myname";` its working. So is there any problem in this line `$userName=$_GET["user"];`.

Comment: The question is not clear. Unable to understand what you want to achieve. Also, you are not calling the function `getuserName()` anywhere!

Comment: yes i am calling it.. But when i call from first eay it will return myname , but the second method will return a null. i want to get th user name from the url and acces store it using $_GET[] method.

Comment: @Sarah Are you trying to call $username from another page? I'm not sure why you've set up the getUserName function

Comment: @Steve im writing this function in authentication.php, im including authentication.php in index and after that the getUserName() is calling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

http://www.mysite.com/index.php?user=myname

**Method 1 :**

```
if(isset($_GET['user'])) {
    $username = $_GET['user'];
} else {
    $username = 'defaultUser';
}
```

**Method 2 :**

```
function getUsername() {
   $username = (isset($_GET['user'])) ? $_GET['user'] : 'defaultUser';
   return $username;
}
```

Second Method uses the ternary [operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). it does the exact same thing as the first method.

P.S : If you consider using above code for database querying do not forget to use `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Comment: @Ibrahim you should correct in `$_GET['user']` instead of `$_GET['name']`, or change your url accordingly. Moreover, care to explain why `mysql_real_escape_string`?? So far your function **WON'T WORK FOR OP**

Comment: Oops sorry, i didn't check the param properly, i am really not sure about OP's Purpose of using $_GET, if it is related to database querying it is always better to have that function attached, and moreover i use that function frequently because i have developed a habit of using it with $_GET given that it contains string.

Comment: If @sarah plans on echoing $username, there isn't much need for escaping, but if she later plans on using it to access a database, she'll need it. It never hurts to escape

Comment: Well, just consider that mysql_real_escape_string returns FALSE if there's no connection, so here it goes your escaping 'just in case'

Comment: @ibrahim She's using $_GET to retrive the user variable from the URL: http://www.mysite.com/index.php?user=myname

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function getUserName()
{

    if(isset($_GET['user'])){   
        return $_GET['user'];
    }else{
        return "defaultuser";
    }
}
```

You need not to have other var, also `$_GET` is superglobal, so you need not global operator